# Displaying Errors on Unsuccessful Save with Ember

Tags: ember.js, error-handling, ember-data

I have a route for `new-thing` and it's template is a form. When this form submits, I call a `createThing` action in the route, passing in `this`.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return {};
  },

  actions: {
    createThing(thing) {
      let thingToSave = this.store.createRecord('thing', {
        name: thing.name,
        description: thing.description
      });

      thingToSave.save().then(function() {
         // happy path
      }).catch(function(reason) {
        // unhappy path
      });
    }
  }
});
```

In my template, I have the following:

```
{{#each model.errors.name as |error|}}
  <div class="error">
    {{error.message}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

But something isn't quite wired up right. I'm unclear on how the route's model ends up being the `thing` I'm trying to save so that the errors will render when the `bad path` triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `model()` should create the blank record:

```
model() {
  return this.store.createRecord('thing');
}
```

That will bind the form fields to your model object.

Then you can save in the route and respond to the results of the HTTP request:

```
actions: {
  createThing() {
    this.get('model').save().then((thing) => {
      // happy path
    },
    (err) => {
      // unhappy path
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha, I had just come up with this. The only thing I'm doing differently is `let this = this.modelFor(this.routeName);` instead of `this.get('model')`. Thanks~

Comment: You're welcome. A great reference for me has been ember 101: https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101 I used that to look up the answer to this question fairly quickly.